# Um compilador C pode gerar um executável de 64 bits onde ponteiros são 32-bits?

Tags: c, ponteiro, 32-bits, 64-bits, compilação

A maioria dos programas se encaixam bem em espaço de endereço de menor que 4GB, mas em alguns casos o programa pode precisar usar os novos recursos/instruções do processador que só estão disponíveis na arquitetura x64. Infelizmente o procedimento normal seria gerar um executável 64 bits e ganhando o custo dos ponteiros terem o dobro do tamanho.

Há aplicações específicas em que a maioria das estruturas de dados tem grande parte de seus elementos compostos por ponteiros. Ponteiros grandes produzirão [cache miss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss)<sup>(en)</sup> com mais frequência e se você não vai usar memória além dos 4GB, ponteiros de 64 bits são puro desperdício.

Existem compiladores onde eu possa usar registradores e instruções específicas x64, mas preservando os ponteiros de 32 bits para economizar a memória? Em quais plataformas?

É possível fazer isso de forma transparente em código legado? Há um *switch/flag* para ligar isso no compilador?

Caso não seja possível trabalhar com código legado, o que é necessário mudar no código para obter os recursos de 64 bits, enquanto mantêm ponteiros de 32 bits?

Eu sei que isto só é vantajoso se essa economia de memória realmente é importante.

Comment: A meu ver isto não deve ser uma preocupação, pois na maioria dos casos as aplicações tem um desempenho superior, quando compiladas na versão 64 bits.
O foco deve ser outro para obter-se desempenho, como por exemplo, cachear as informações mais utilizadas ou que tenham alto custo de I/O.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sim, isso é possivel.

No entanto entenda que isso não é uma alteração tão simples quanto parece. Bibliotecas de 32-bits esperam que você passe argumentos pelos registros em determinado formato, e que ponteiros sejam 4 bytes. As 64-bits usam outro formado incompatível e os ponteiros de 8 bytes. Se você vai usar ponteiros de 4 bytes e todo o resto dos recursos iguais a como seria em 64-bits, nenhuma das duas versões da biblioteca será compatível com seu programa. Isso significa basicamente que você precisará compilar todas as bibliotecas que for usar nesse formato.

Outro problema está no kernel. Ao fazer uma *system call*, argumentos também são passados de forma diferenciada. Então você precisará também de suporte especial do kernel para rodar um programa assim.

Isso é implementado como uma nova arquitetura, a x32:

[image] [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)

Para compilar um programa em modo x32, você precisará de um ambiente linux razoavelmente moderno:

- Linux 64-bits versão 3.4 compilado com a opção CONFIG_X86_X32.
- GLIBC 2.16
- GCC 4.7
- Binutils 2.22

Minha instalação padrão do ubuntu vem com esses requerimentos. Compilar um programa em modo x32 é simples: adicione a *flag* `-mx32` ao gcc. Pude executar os programas compilados sem nenhum procedimento adicional e observando o assembly gerado fica claro que registradores de 64-bits são utilizados, mesmo com ponteiros de 32-bits.

Como é um recurso relativamente novo (integrado ao kernel no fim de 2011) e pouco utilizado (ou seja, pouco testado em produção), é possivel que problemas menores sejam encontrados.

Se não quiser mudar de arquitetura e preferir algo mais "estável", uma outra opção seria trocar todos os ponteiros por `uint32_t` e fazer uma conversão sempre que necessário. Não há perda de performance já que essa conversão não gera instruções. No entanto há o problema de o ponteiro apontar para algo além dos 4GB. Isso acontecerá, por exemplo, para todos os ponteiros da stack, já que a stack se inicia no fim da memória virtual do processo.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se ajuda, mas no Visual C++ existe a flag de linkagem `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, que permite que um executável 32bits acesse até 3 gigas de RAM, em vez de 2, quando roda em uma versão 64 do Windows.

Eu uso isso no trabalho, pois temos um programa que frequentemente precisa alocar mais do que 2 gigas.

De acordo com a [documentação da flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx), é possível passar `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO` para programas 64, o que limita esse programas a 2 giga de RAM. É possível que isso faça com que os ponteiros fiquem também em 32 bits, mas não verifiquei.