# Alocação de objetos e ponteiros

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Como acontece a alocação de um ponteiro que aponta para uma classe, e a de um objeto? Há diferença? Tamanho, etc.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer um pouco mais o que deseja? Diferença do que em relação a que?

Comment: Acho que é essa mesma dúvida : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50165/quando-devo-escolher-entre-utilizar-ou-n%C3%A3o-um-ponteiro-ao-criar-um-objeto/50171#50171

Comment: Objeto é uma classe instanciada. Não há diferença entre ponteiros comuns (que apontam para uma struct, por exemplo) de um objeto. O que muda é a semântica entre eles (por exemplo na resolução de métodos virtuais). Especifique um pouco mais sua dúvida, e poderei explicar melhor.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Ponteiros não apontam para classes e sim para objetos. Classes são conceitos abstratos que existem durante a definição de sua forma no código, após a compilação elas não existem. Podem existir alguns dados estáticos contidos nela, aí sim poderia ter um apontamento para estes dados individualmente. Talvez seja isto que você está chamando de classe. Mas no fundo estes dados [não deixam de ser objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).

Objetos podem estar em diversos locais, eles não precisam ter ponteiros para eles. Se ele for uma instância de uma classe então **provavelmente** terá ponteiro apontando para ele.

Ponteiro é ponteiro, o tamanho não varia em uma mesma arquitetura. Em arquiteturas de 16 bits eles possuem tamanho de 2 bytes. Em arquiteturas 32 bits, que era a mais comum, ele tem 4 bytes. Em arquiteturas 64 bits eles possuem 8 bytes. Como o ponteiro indica um endereço de memória e 64 bits permite endereçar 16 Hexabytes, acho que não veremos isto estourar (na prática algumas arquiteturas limitam isto um pouco porque ninguém precisa disto tudo agora e fica mais barato reduzir).

Há mais informações sobre isto [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54769/101). Há [uma curiosidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1986/101) de como é possível utilizar um arquitetura em uma plataforma específica e ainda alocar ponteiros com tamanho diferente.

Estratégias de utilização [nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101) (lá tem um *link* para explicação da diferença entre *stack* e *heap* que é importante). Ainda que possa ter ponteiros para o *stack*, isto é menos comum já que a informação está muito mais próxima e ela é fugaz. O código costuma apontar para endereços do *stack* mas estes apontamentos não costumam ser considerados ponteiros, pelo menos no sentido do que você parece estar falando, afinal nem há alocação neste caso.

[Pergunta para entender ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

A alocação dele é um dado como outro qualquer. Na maioria das plataformas ele é confundido com um `int` e estes dois tipos de dados podem ser intercambiados (alguns casos pode ser um `long`), ou seja, você pode pegar um ponteiro e considerá-lo como um inteiro e vice-versa, ainda que se isto não for feito com cuidado, pode ser desastroso. Os ponteiros podem ser alocados no *stack* ou no *heap*.

Pode haver um *overhead* extra de consumo de memória por causa da alocação do objeto no *heap*, mas isto não tem relação com o ponteiro. Este *overhead* - uma área administrativa de alocação - é relacionado com o gerenciamento de memória utilizado pelo sistema operacional ou por um gerenciador próprio do *runtime* da linguagem ou da aplicação. Isto pode variar, mas em muitas implementações ele é de 8 bytes em 32 bits (duas [palavras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101)). Nem estou falando do alinhamento da memória que é outro assunto.

[Artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

[Artigo](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/) que mostra o funcionamento da alocação da memória.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: não necessariamente o ponteiro tem 64 bits em um arquitetura de 64 bits. Por exemplo, os binários x32 são binários x86-64 mas com tamanho de ponteiro de 32 bits. Ela foi inventada exatamente por causa desse overhead no tamanho dos ponteiros, já que a maioria dos aplicativos não utilizam nem os 4GB de memória que os 32 bits permitem endereçar.

Comment: É, eu explico isto nas minhas outras respostas *linkadas*.

Comment: Ah sim. Não li elas =] Foi mal!