# Por que não estoura a pilha?

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, memória, stack

Com esse código, o livro me diz que isso não estoura a pilha, mas por que exatamente não estoura?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int *p;
   while(1){
      p = new int;
   }
}
```

Comment: Porque estouraria? Tem só uma variável na pilha.

Comment: mas o laço while fz o progrma fica em um loop eterno ?

Comment: Quando você usa `new`, você está usando alocação dinâmica propriamente dita. Normalmente a pilha fica com as coisas estáticas, não dinâmicas. Você teria um estouro de pilha se fizesse `int main() { main(); }`, pois aí estaria empilhando chamada da função `main` sobre `main`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De forma simplificada podemos considerar que existem duas grandes áreas para alocação e manipulação de memória:

Stack(pilha)

Heap(monte).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A stack ou pilha é uma área bem menor e a heap ou monte é uma área de memória bem maior. A stack tem no windows um tamanho padrão de apenas 1MB(um megabyte)!

No entanto, essa região de memória de pilha é bem mais eficaz para localizar e manipular recursos se comparado a heap.

Ao declararmos variáveis locais  elas ficarão alocadas na Stack

Ponteiros também ficam na stack e chamadas de funções são empilhadas na stack

Assim se você rodar o código abaixo ocorrerá o erro stack overflow, pois haverá tentativa de alocar 3 milhoes e 300 mil inteiros da variável vetor que é local da função main().

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int vetor[3300000]; 
 //TENTANDO ALOCAR 3 MILHOES E 300 MIL INTEIROS
    printf("Esta linha não será exibida pois ocorrerá antes STACKOVERFLOW");

    return 0;
}
```

Bem, se considerarmos no windows que um inteiro ocupa 4B(quatro Bytes) temos então a tentativa de alocar
3.300.000 x 4B = 13.200.000 Bytes
1MB(um megabyte) equivale a 1.048.576 Bytes

13.200.000B /1.048.576B EQUIVALE A 12,58MB(doze virgula cinquenta e oito megabytes) 
Muito maior que 1MB de espaço na pilha(stack)
Logo, VAI ESTOURAR!

Veja o que ocorre ao executar este código no Visual Studio Community 2015:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No seu código o que ocorre?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int *p; // aloca uma variável ponteiro na stack(pilha)
   while(1){ //loop infinito
      p = new int; // a variável p contida na pilha recebe o endereço de memória alocado para um inteiro através de new
   }
}
```

Observe que new aloca memória na Heap que é muito maior
portanto durante todo o programa o loop infinito irá:
Criar uma nova região de memória para alocar um inteiro(possivelmente de 4KB) 
e o endereço desta região de memória será atribuída na variável ponteiro p que está na stack
Então observe que a variável ponteiro p não está sendo criada novamente!
O que está ocorrendo é apenas a mudança do endereço contido dentro dela.
Claro, 4 novos KB estão sendo alocados na Heap a cada loop, mas isso não será suficiente para ocupar toda a heap em pouco tempo. Se isso ocorrer ocorreria erro de tentativa de invasão de memória além da alocada inicialmente para o programa*(Veja este assunto de registrador base e limite na disciplina Sistemas Operacionais)*

Obs: 
Os programas em linguagem C típicos usam  as funções malloc e free que aloca e desaloca na memória heap. 
Em C++ existe new e delete que também  aloca e desaloca objetos na memória heap, mas com aprimoramentos de debug de gerenciamento de memória úteis para detectar possíveis vazamentos de memória.
(veja também ponteiros inteligentes std::unique_ptr e std::shared_ptr em c++?)

Comment: obg cara essa foi a melhor explicação, eu estou apreendendo  c++ com um livro ,eu venho do java  nunca  tive q lidar com gerenciamento de memoria ate agr ,mas essa explicação me tirou muitas duvidas  (P.S NOSSA O WINDOWS TEM SO 1 MEGA DE ESPAÇO ,POR ISSO Q OS PONTEIROS SAO  TAO UTEIS ) OBRIGADAO

Comment: Obrigado Dougllas, Veja que editei a coloquei agora o tamanho correto que um inteiro ocupa no windows que é de 4 ou 8 Bytes! Veja as novas contas! Abraço

Answer (score 6):

A variável `p` foi declarada nessa função. Ela terá o tamanho de 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura. Essa variável é única em toda a função e ao que parece toda aplicação é este código. Por que estouraria a pilha com apenas uma variável de tão pouco tamanho?

A pilha tem tamanho fixo, não tem porque estourar. O estouro só ocorre quando ela vai sendo ocupada cada vez mais, o que não ocorre. Obviamente que se ninguém parar essa aplicação ela nunca terminará.

Em algum momento a aplicação ficará bem lenta ou terá problema com o *heap* porque a memória virtual tem limite e há limite de RAM.

Se a arquitetura for 32 bits quando rodar pouco mais de 1 bilhão de vezes, ocupará os 4GBB da memória total. Como nem tudo deve estar em RAM deverá ter alguma lentidão para jogar em armazenamento secundário. Se tiver um SSD de última geração nem sentirá tanto assim.

Se a arquitetura for 64 bits precisará mais de 4 quintilhões de interações para encher todo espaço, claro que precisará de um armazenamento secundário preparado para suportar tamanha memória virtual, precisaria centenas de HDDs com a capacidade atual. Acho que levaria alguns séculos para rodar isso com hardware atual.

Se tirar o `new` não há mais alocação em *heap*, então é tudo feito na pilha, sempre no mesmo lugar, já que sempre existe uma só variável, então aí nem o *heap* pode estourar. A pilha, em essência, deixando de lado pequenos detalhes, ocupará 4 bytes (pode ser diferente, mas na prática será 4 bytes).

O operador `new` é o responsável pela alocação no *heap* e ele está sendo executado diversas vezes alocando um inteiro em cada vez, o que [nem é apenas 4 bytes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101), mas isso é outro assunto. Ele retorna sempre um ponteiro que é armazenado em `p` sobrepondo o valor anterior, ou seja, o objeto criado anteriormente fica sem nenhum ponteiro apontando para ele, fica inacessível. Como não é dado um `delete` no objeto, ele fica lá ocupando espaço sem necessidade.

Em uma linguagem de memória gerenciada isto não ocorreria e o coletor de lixo iria liberando memória.

[Veja mais sobre a *stack* e o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, a pilha não está enchendo, mas o heap está? Conforme o heap enche, começa-se a usar o armazenamento do HD/SSD ao invés da RAM? Se sim, haveria "estouro de heap" em algum momento (pelo HD/SSD ficar cheio ou por algum "limite pré-definido" estourar)?

Comment: pq a heap esta enchendo se é apenas um ponteiro ?

Comment: Basta encher o que foi reservado pelo sistema operacional para memória virtual e haverá estouro de memória. O ponteiro só existe um de cada vez e fica na pilha, conforme está na resposta. O *heap* está enchendo porque a cada iteração do laço está mandando alocar um novo inteiro no *heap*, com o operador `new`. E nunca está mandando desalocar, como deveria em algum momento que ele não seja mais necessário. Cada alocação gera um ponteiro, só que ele está sendo jogado em cima do ponteiro anterior já que só há uma variável.

Comment: Inclusive todas essas alocações não podem ser acessadas pelo código já que o ponteiro para cada uma delas é perdido logo depois de outro ser criado.

Comment: entao a cada loop o p esta recebendo mais 4 bits de memoria

Comment: mas o operador new  é chamado varias vezes pelo q entendo ele aloca mais memoria .

Comment: Não, ele está alocando 4 bytes (a grosso modo) no *heap*. Isto porque o `new` está sendo chamado a cada vez. O `p` recebe 4 ou 8 bytes do ponteiro onde houve a alocação, mas está sobrepondo porque só existe uma variável. Agora vou encerrar aqui porque estou só repetindo o que já foi dito antes.

Comment: ok obg acho q eu estou confundindo  stack e  heap,

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101

Comment: OBRIGADAO  agr sim ficou claro ,eu estava confundindo o heap com stack

Comment: Blz, é uma pena que você preferiu a resposta que tem vários erros. Por ela está negativada enquanto a minha tem vários votos, mas se deseja aprender errado, só você perderá.