# Alocação dinâmica em C - alocando sem saber a quantidade total de elementos

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação, malloc

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a alocação dinâmica em c, quanto ao uso da função `malloc()`.

Se pegarmos, por exemplo, um caso de cadastro de um nome completo, como não temos como saber a quantidade de caracteres, nós criamos o `malloc()`, dessa forma, o campo irá se ajustar ao tamanho exato digitado pelo usuário, correto?

Mas em todo exemplo que vejo, há a inserção da quantidade de bytes que serão alocados, exemplo:

```
char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor;
```

Ou seja, nesse caso vou estar alocando `quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor` vezes o tamanho de um `char`.
Entretanto, o objeto de usar `malloc()`, não seria porque não sei a quantidade total de elementos?

Ou seja, não preciso chutar um tamanho estático, delimitando a quantidade máxima de elementos. Usando essa variável `quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor` não tira esse propósito?

Se eu sei a quantidade total de elementos, qual a diferença então de já definir um tamanho estático? Exemplo:

```
char c[20];
```

O que eu sei é que, se eu fazer uma alocação dinâmica, a alocação de memória será feita na execução do programa, e não na sua compilação, como ocorre quando há a definição de um vetor estático.

O motivo de ter que usar uma alocação do tipo:

```
char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor;
```

Seria porque em linguagem C, preciso saber o tamanho do meu vetor para conseguir percorre o mesmo?

Ainda usando essa linha de código acima como exemplo, se eu dizer que:

```
quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor = 20;
```

Quer dizer que estarei alocando 20 bytes (sizeof(char) * 20, considerando que tamanho de um char é igual a 1), certo? E se nesse caso, eu entrasse uma palavra que tivesse apenas 10 caracteres? Eu iria ocupar apenas os 10 primeiros espaços e os outros 10? Haveria um desperdício nesse caso então?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Se pegarmos, por exemplo, um caso de cadastro de um nome completo, como não temos como saber a quantidade de caracteres, nós criamos o `malloc()`, dessa forma, o campo irá se ajustar ao tamanho exato digitado pelo usuário, correto?

Geralmente não, é comum você estabelecer um tamanho máximo que o nome terá e aloca essa quantia. Eventualmente podem ser feitas otimizações posteriores se for necessário. Quase sempre você escolhe se quer ter o melhor consumo de memória ou o menor processamento possível.

É possível usar uma estratégia de [`realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), mas em grande parte dos casos não compensa o esforço. Ela vai crescendo a alocação conforme a necessidade, mas quase sempre é uma solução pior. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101).

> Mas em todo exemplo que vejo há a inserção da quantidade de bytes que serão alocados, exemplo:

> ```
> char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor;
> ```

> Ou seja, nesse caso estarei alocando `quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor` vezes o tamanho de um `char`. Entretanto, o objeto de usar `malloc()`, não seria porque não sei a quantidade total de elementos?

Não, o objetivo do seu uso é alocar na memória dinâmica, geralmente o [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (pelo menos é assim em todas implementações "sérias" de C padrão. Só isso, você tem que saber a quantidade de *bytes* a ser alocado.

> Ou seja, não preciso chutar um tamanho estático, delimitando a quantidade máxima de elementos. Usando essa variável `quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor` não tira esse propósito?

Seu conceito de "tamanho estático" e todo uso do termo estático por aí está incorreto, o estático é outra coisa, é algo que é imutável desde a inicialização da aplicação e definido durante a compilação, portanto não podem receber valores em tempo de execução.

Veja [O que impede um array de ser inicializado com um tamanho variável em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106719/101). Ou ainda [Como armazenar uma string qualquer em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101).

E qual é o tamanho de `char`? [É sempre 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178443/101), então eu tenho vontade de chorar quando usam `sizeof(char)`.

> Se eu sei a quantidade total de elementos, qual a diferença então de já definir um tamanho estático? Exemplo:

> ```
> char c[20];
> ```

Essa sintaxe determina que é alocado na memória automática (que não é estática), ou seja, a *stack* (portanto só existirá no escopo onde foi criado). É a única diferença importante para o [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), até porque o `malloc()` também exige um tamanho conhecido. Não existe mágica, não existe elasticidade. Veja [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro para vetor e ponteiro para variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193507/101).

> O que eu sei é que, se eu fizer uma alocação dinâmica, a alocação de memória será feita na execução do programa, e não na sua compilação, como ocorre quando há a definição de um vetor estático.

Na prática toda alocação é feita na execução. Não existe isso de alocação na compilação. Existe alocação definida durante a compilação que ocorre na área estática. Mesmo na área automática o tamanho pode ser definido no momento da necessidade, e claro, ela será feita só na execução. Algo assim é permitido:

```
char c[x]; //x é lido pelo teclado antes desta linha
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/DynamicSize.c).

> O motivo de ter que usar uma alocação do tipo:

> ```
> char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor;
> ```

> Seria porque em linguagem C, preciso saber o tamanho do meu vetor para conseguir percorre o mesmo?

Não, isso está incorreto. Usa assim porque quer que o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) do objeto seja desassociado do tempo de vida da função (a tal da área automática) que o criou, ou então você quer garantir que o tamanho do objeto não crie [complicadores para a pilha que tem um tamanho limitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/221456/101), nesse caso está se assegurando porque sabe que potencialmente o objeto pode ser grande demais e até mesmo dar um [*stack Overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101).

> Ainda usando essa linha de código acima como exemplo, se eu dizer que:

> ```
> quantidade_de_elementos_que_vou_ter_no_meu_vetor = 20;
> ```

Isso apenas está atribuindo o valor `20` para uma variável com nome muito longo que já deve estar declarada previamente. O resto é especulação.

> Quer dizer que estarei alocando 20 bytes (`sizeof(char) * 20`, considerando que tamanho de um char é igual a 1), certo?

Sim.

> E se nesse caso, eu entrasse uma palavra que tivesse apenas 10 caracteres? Eu iria ocupar apenas os 10 primeiros espaços e os outros 10? Haveria um desperdício nesse caso então?

De certa forma, sim. Não sei se dá para chamar de desperdício, mas de fato ele fica sem uso. É normal. Há tantos outros "desperdícios" que a maioria dos programadores nunca se dão conta. Há casos que o "desperdício" ([*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101)) de um vetor na *stack* é menor, ou pelo menos não muito maior que o do uso do `malloc()`. Quase todas implementações de `malloc()` "desperdiçam" espaço (as que não o fazem tem outros problemas piores, por isso nem são usadas de fato). Sem falar que é muito mais complicado gerenciá-lo. E e tem uma [performance pior em quase todos casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101). Ele deveria ser sempre a última opção na maioria dos cenários.

Pode ser útil:

- [As variáveis são alocadas aleatoriamente na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252011/101)
- [Como o malloc() organiza a memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254358/101)
- [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101)
- [Variáveis declaradas dentro de blocos ou subprogramas são alocadas dinamicamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280973/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

> como não temos como saber a quantidade de caracteres, nós criamos o malloc, dessa forma, o campo ira se ajustar ao tamanho exato digitado pelo usuário, correto?

Incorreto, tanto em alocação estática como dinamica o tamanho tem que ser definido e não existe nenhum ajuste automatico. Se reservou espaço para 20 carateres então só pode guardar 20 careteres.

> Mas em todo exemplo que vejo, há a inserção da quantidade de bytes que serão alocados

É precisamente como a função funciona. Se olhar para a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) você vê que apenas um parametro é recebido, a quantidade de bytes a alocar. Isto significa que `malloc(34)` indica que quer requisitar uma area de na memória com 34 bytes de tamanho. Logo fica ao seu critério de dizer a quantidade de bytes correta para o que você pretende guardar.

> Entretanto, o objeto de usar malloc, não seria porque não sei a quantidade total de elementos?

Nem por isso. A maior motivação para usar alocação dinamica seria fazer com que o espaço de memoria se mantenha até que seja feito `free`. Em contraste, na alocação estática que exemplificou com `char c[20];` no fim da função esse array de chars é liberado e não pode mais aceder a ele.

> E se nesse caso, eu entrasse uma palavra que tivesse apenas 10 caracteres? Eu iria ocupar apenas os 10 primeiros espaços e os outros 10? Haveria um desperdício nesse caso então?

Usa os primeiros 10 e ainda tem de usar mais um para o terminador, senão não tem uma string corretamente terminada. Os restantes ficam por utilizar e tem o valor que já estava na memória, que aos nossos olhos acabam por ser aleatorios.

Answer (score 0):

**Você tem razão, mas não tem razão ;)**

Quando você aloca memória tem que saber quanto vai alocar, é o parâmetro para `malloc()`: o número de bytes.

Mas você está talvez resumindo demais o problema: seguindo com seu exemplo de nome, vamos focar em nomes de cidades e considerar 4, com o número de letras entre parenteses. incluído um espaço para o zero final:

```
Santos (7) 
Brasília (9)
Itú (4)
itapecirica da Serra (21)
```

Quando você criar um cadastro de cidades usando um tamanho fixo para cada cidade vai alocar memória para esses nomes usando que tamanho? O tamanho da "maior" cidade, certo?

```
char cidades[4][21];
```

Para essas 4 serão 84 bytes. No entanto elas só tem 41 no total. Com essas 4 cidades já se foram 43 bytes em desperdício.

É por isso que se usa UMA área estática, grande o suficiente para conter o nome mais longo de cidade, como

```
char uma_cidade[512];
```

e a partir dessa área se cria uma estrutura como

```
char** cidades;
int    nCidades;
```

para guardar as cidades todas e o número de cidades, usando alocação dinâmica e alocando apenas o espaço necessário para o nome da cidade e um 0 no fim para terminar a string.

Qualquer semelhança com o que o sistema faz com todo programa C é porque é a mesma coisa: o protótipo de `main()` é

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

e o sistema monta a lista com os argumentos, cada um uma string, terminada por zero, e diz em `argc` quantos são. E se você chama seu programa `x` assim:

```
x azul 32 verde
```

seu programa recebe

```
argc = 4;
argv[0] = "C:\x.exe"
argv[1] = "azul"
argv[2] = "32"
argv[3] = "verde"
```

todas as strings com o tamanho mínimo e terminadas por zero.

[Postei um exemplo que faz isso para int**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468229/108192)

> Seria porque em linguagem C, preciso saber o tamanho do meu vetor para
> conseguir percorre o mesmo?

No caso de um vetor de `char`, a tal string, em C elas são terminadas por zero e você pode percorrer com essa noção: até o zero. E assim cada string tem ao menos um byte.
No caso de outras estruturas você precisa sim saber o tamanho, como no caso de `argv[]` em que o sistema gentilmente te dá o `argc`.

> > Entretanto, o objeto de usar `malloc()`, não seria porque não sei a quantidade total de >>elementos?

Acho que já entendeu a razão agora: na dúvida entre alocar milhares de registros com o tamanho certo ou milhares de registros do tamanho do maior registro de todos a opção em geral é por alocar todos do tamanho certo