# Desenvolver para plataformas x86 e x64

Tags: .net, sistema-operacional, x86, x64

Cada vez mais os sistema operacionais vêm priorizando a "versão" `64bits`, com isso, o desenvolvimento aplicações para esta arquitetura fica cada vez mais atraente.

- Com base neste cenário, venho perguntar quais as vantagens/desvantagens de desenvolver para a plataforma x64?
- Para tirar proveito desta arquitetura é necessário algum tipo de aplicação específica, ex: Edição imagens, Jogos, etc?
- Meu projeto está configurado como `Platform target: Any Cpu` automaticamente terei versão 32 e 64bits?

Comment: Complementar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1986/101

Comment: A pergunta responde algumas questões. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De uma maneira geral não precisa nada específico, ainda mais em .Net que se vira em qual plataforma vai rodar. Claro que pode haver algumas incompatibilidades com coisas que sejam externas ao .NET e estejam em 32 bits. Código nativo tem mais dificuldade de compatibilizar as duas formas, ainda que possível. O .NET compila para código nativo do jeito que você mandar na hora de executar e se vira para fazer tudo funcionar dentro dele.

O .NET ajustará a aplicação ao que for mais adequado onde for executado. As regras podem mudar. O padrão era tentar usar 32 bits sempre que possível (carregou em um processo 32 bits) mas não sei se mudou em versões mais recentes. Dá para configurar isso na máquina destino.

Na maioria dos casos não vai causar problemas, mas há quem diga que o [ideal é escolher uma plataforma ou outra](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201160836/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx), mas não sei se isto ainda é válido. Claro que isto tem lá suas desvantagens.

## Vantagens

A maior vantagem de usar 64 bits é a possibilidade de endereçar mais que 4GB de memória. O que na prática significa poder acessar mais de 2GB de memória na mesma aplicação.

Outra vantagem é que algumas instruções e registradores do processador podem ser acessados neste modo, pode ter uma performance maior e fazer algumas coisas extras. Especialmente cálculos de números grandes podem ser feitos em menos ciclos. Inteiros "longos" e números de dupla precisão cabem no registrador. Isto não é a mesma coisa que dizer que a aplicação será mais rápida. Veja as desvantagens.

Também podemos contar como vantagem o fato de rodar de forma direta em sistemas operacionais 64 bits sem adaptações.

Uma outra vantagem que não é intrínseca, mas na prática está acontecendo com o .NET e antes era uma desvantagem, tudo que era para 64 bits era algo de segunda classe. Agora está sendo feito investimentos nas ferramentas para esta arquitetura. E estão usando técnicas mais modernas. Cada vez mais teremos melhores ferramentas para 64 bits do que para 32 bits. Um exemplo claro é o novo [JITter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler-for-net/) ([o que é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)).

## Desvantagens

Nem tudo são flores.

O consumo de memória aumenta já que todo endereçamento precisa de 8 bytes em vez de 4. Não é nada que faça tanta diferença em quase todos os casos. Se costuma adotar a regra de só usar um sistema operacional 32 bits com uma máquina com pelo menos 4GB de memória.

Isto pode atrapalhar um pouco o cache, que hoje é uma das coisas que mais ajudam a performance. Quanto maior forem as informações, menos delas cabem no cache, que é bem pequeno. Isto é um problema real que as pessoas costumam negligenciar. O mesmo vale para disparar o *garbage collector* e pressionar o *stack*.

Se o sistema operacional for 32 bits, não roda. O que não é um problema para o .NET, porque ele pode escolher. A não ser que a aplicação exija um consumo de memória acima de 2GB.

[Complemento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101). [Diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1986/101).